# No available formula for “pdfunite” in Homebrew?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, bash, homebrew

I am on Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and I am new to Bash. I am trying to install [`pdfunite`](https://github.com/mtgrosser/pdfunite). I installed [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) and ran the following command:

```
brew install pdfunite
```

And I received

> Error: No available formula for pdfunite
>
> Searching formulae...
>
> Searching taps...

And indeed after that, if I use `pdfunite` I get the error “command not found.”

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It’s not part of the `brew` repository - the utility requires that you install `poppler` first according to [the Github source](https://github.com/mtgrosser/pdfunite)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To have `pdfunite` working on OSX, you need to install [`poppler`](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.7/general/poppler.html)—which is described as “…a PDF rendering library and command line tools used to manipulate PDF files.”—instead:

```
brew install poppler
```

Comment: Read [the answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1155535/411849) - Ruby and Gem are needed for pdfunite.

Comment: Just `brew install poppler` was enough. pdfunite was available after that

Answer (score 9):

The procedure seems to work a little differently for me. Here's what I've got and hope it would help:

```
brew install poppler
gem install pdfunite
```

Then I double checked to see if `pdfunite` is installed.

```
gem search ^pdfunite
## *** REMOTE GEMS ***
## pdfunite (0.3.0)
```

Initially, I was confused whether to use it over Ruby (`irb`) or just command line. It turns out that you use it in the command line, which is great. For example, to merge my 2 files in the Downloads folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
pdfunite -h #check how to type the syntax
## Usage: pdfunite [options] <PDF-sourcefile-1>..<PDF-sourcefile-n> <PDF-destfile>
pdfunite file1.pdf file2.pdf compiled.pdf #tab-completion is supported
```

Comment: Just `brew install poppler` worked for me to get pdfunite working. I didn't need the `gem install pdfunite`